# GitHub unit test failes on configuration using Karma

Tags: angular, github-actions, karma-jasmine

I am trying to run on github pipeline and I added test section. So all tests passes but it ends with this error

```
    ✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
12 01 2024 08:38:12.950:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v6.4.2 server started at http://localhost:9876/
12 01 2024 08:38:12.952:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers ChromeHeadless with concurrency unlimited
12 01 2024 08:38:12.959:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser ChromeHeadless
12 01 2024 08:38:16.312:INFO [Chrome Headless 120.0.6099.199 (Linux x86_64)]: Connected on socket DWOuKXQLVla7uEp-AAAB with id 43272771
Chrome Headless 120.0.6099.199 (Linux x86_64): Executed 0 of 2 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome Headless 120.0.6099.199 (Linux x86_64): Executed 1 of 2 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.076 secs)
Chrome Headless 120.0.6099.199 (Linux x86_64): Executed 2 of 2 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.088 secs)
Chrome Headless 120.0.6099.199 (Linux x86_64): Executed 2 of 2 SUCCESS (0.147 secs / 0.088 secs)
TOTAL: 2 SUCCESS
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
- Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
12 01 2024 08:38:30.019:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v6.4.2 server started at http://localhost:9876/
12 01 2024 08:38:30.020:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers ChromeHeadless with concurrency unlimited
12 01 2024 08:38:30.023:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser ChromeHeadless
12 01 2024 08:38:30.260:INFO [Chrome Headless 120.0.6099.199 (Linux x86_64)]: Connected on socket ZG7l0ICZB34c5IMgAAAD with id 30559897
Chrome Headless 120.0.6099.199 (Linux x86_64): Executed 0 of 0 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome Headless 120.0.6099.199 (Linux x86_64): Executed 0 of 0 SUCCESS (0.009 secs / 0 secs)
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
TOTAL: 0 SUCCESS
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I am not sure what does this mean and why this is happening cause locally all passes correctly

running command is here:  `"test:prod": "ng test --browsers=ChromeHeadless --no-watch",`

karma.conf.js file content is here

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      '**/*.spec.ts',
      '*.spec.ts',
    ],
    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {
      '**/*.spec.ts': ['webpack'],
      '*.spec.ts': ['webpack'],
    },
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadless: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--no-sandbox', '--remote-debugging-port=9222'],
      },
    },
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: 2,  // Adjust the concurrency level as needed
  });
};
```

tsconfig.spec.json content is here

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": ["jasmine", "@angular/localize"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.spec.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts"]
}
```

Comment: I have figured out that it is running two rounds, one is successful with 2 tests but then gitHub starts another round but this fails, dont understand why.

Answer (score 0):

As this becomes habit, that you need to find solution yourself in most of the cases, this is the same example.

I found solution myself, so if anybody will experience this problem, solution is.
**Look for any other tsconfig.spec.json which in my case was in library generated in my project and it was also set in angular.json so from this reason, it executed another round for this file.**

ChatGPT is in more cases better helper then this forum, which is pity.

Comment: It is ironic that you criticise this forum and congratulate ChatGPT that is largely fed from the answers of this forum. Also, understanding what you are doing is the best way to succeed. Forums are supposed to help you when you are stuck, not give you solutions before you even learnt. The setup that you use to test is needlessly complex and you probably did copy it from a tutorial or a "GitHub skeleton project". That's on you if you think this is how you'll learn and get better.